# Unity rotation angles stuck between -90 and 90 degress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a movement system in which the player only controls the rotation of the airplane, not the movement itself, the airplane perpetually goes forward, but for some reason the rotation always stays between -90 and 90 degreess.

Here is the RotatePlayer method, it is called on every FixedUpdate.

```
private void RotatePlayer()
{
    Vector2 inputVector = _playerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    if (inputVector != Vector2.zero)
    {
            Vector3 rotationDirection = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, 0f);
            var rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(rotationDirection), Time.deltaTime * 100f);
            Debug.Log(rotation);
            transform.rotation = rotation;
            //_playerRigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * inputVector.x * _rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues here is that `rotationDirection` will be normalized and used as a direction which will always be one of the following three options

- `Vector3.zero` if there is no input (you catch away that case with the if)
- `Vector3.left` for any negative `inputVector.x`
- `Vector3.right` for any positive `inputVector.x`

It doesn't even matter at all how much the input is actually pressed!

So

```
var rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(rotationDirection), Time.deltaTime * 100f);
transform.rotation = rotation;
```

can always maximum reach that directions aligned with the world space X axis.

---

You would rather want to **add** your input to the current rotation and do something like e.g.

```
var inputVector = _playerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
var rotationSpeed = inputVector.x * SOME_MULTIPLIER * Time.deltaTime;
trabsform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, rotationSpeed, 0));
 // basically equals doing
 //transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationSpeed, 0);
```

or if actually using physics you might want to rather go for

```
rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationSpeed, 0));
```

Comment: You rock, I love you.